# Proxy API(single custom php) does not work from Mozilla firefox browser and working with chrome and postman

Tags: php

> Here is the my custom php file as a proxy api. Every thing is working
>   in Chrome but not found error even i directly access a get request
>   from browser url.

**I am accessing the api from Angular ts.
So when i access directly the server(Yii2 framework used) without proxy api it is working for me.
So what i need to add to this file so the Mozila can access my api's**

```
class Api
{

    /**
     * Get response from url
     * @param $url
     * @param $params
     * @param $header
     * @param $body
     * @return bool|string|null
     */
    public static function getResponse($url, $params, $header, $body)
    {
        if($params)
        $url = $url . '?' . $params;
        $referer = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
        $userAgent = 'ZvaApiProxy/1.0';

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10); // Good leeway for redirections.
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR , "cookie.txt");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, trim($url));

        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
        } else if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT') {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
        } else if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'DELETE') {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
        }

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        http_response_code($httpcode);
        curl_close($ch);
        if (!isset($response))
            return null;
        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * Get headers
     * @return array|false|string
     */
    public function getHeaders()
    {
        return getallheaders();
    }

    /**
     * Get params
     * @return string
     */
    public function getParams()
    {
        return http_build_query($_GET);
    }

    /**
     * Get path info
     * @return mixed|string
     */
    public function getPathInfo()
    {
        if(isset($_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'])){
        $str = substr($_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'], 11);
        $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'] = $str;
        }
       return !empty($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']) ? $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] : (!empty($_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']) ? $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'] : '');
       // return $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'];
    }
    public function getAction(){

    }
    /**
     * Get body
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBody()
    {
        switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
            case 'GET':
                return http_build_query($_GET);
                break;
            case 'POST':
                return http_build_query($_POST);
                break;
            case 'DELETE':
                return http_build_query($_GET);
                break;
            case 'PUT':
                return http_build_query($_POST);
                break;
        }
    }
}

$modal = new Api();
$baseUrl = 'http://dev-api.abc';
echo $modal::getResponse($baseUrl . $modal->getPathInfo(), $modal->getParams(), $modal->getHeaders(), $modal->getBody());
```

Here the network detail
[image]

Comment: "Not working" means exactly what? Please read the ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update yours.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Please see the above added image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please comment out the lines i have commented this working for me

```
<?php

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
        header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
        header("access-control-allow-origin: *");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 10');    // cache for 1 day
    }

class Api
{

    /**
     * Get response from url
     * @param $url
     * @param $params
     * @param $header
     * @param $body
     * @return bool|string|null
     */
    public static function getResponse($url, $params, $header, $body)
    {
         if($params)
                 $url = $url . '?' . $params;

        //$referer = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
        //$userAgent = 'ZvaApiProxy/1.0';
        $ch = curl_init();
       // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
         //  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
            //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
       // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
      // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
       // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
       // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
      //  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10); // Good leeway for redirections.
       // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR , "cookie.txt");
//        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  //      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, trim($url));

        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
        } else if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT') {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
        } else if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'DELETE') {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
        }
         //  for error
         //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

           http_response_code($httpcode);
          curl_close($ch);
        if (!isset($response))
            return null;

        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * Get headers
     * @return array|false|string
     */
    public function getHeaders()
    {
        return getallheaders();
    }

    /**
     * Get params
     * @return string
     */
    public function getParams()
    {
        return http_build_query($_GET);
    }

    /**
     * Get path info
     * @return mixed|string
     */
    public function getPathInfo()
    {

        if(isset($_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'])){
        $str = substr($_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'], 11);
        $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'] = $str;
        }

       return !empty($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']) ? $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] : (!empty($_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']) ? $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'] : '');
       // return $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'];
    }
    public function getAction(){

    }
    /**
     * Get body
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBody()
    {
        switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
            case 'GET':
                return http_build_query($_GET);
                break;
            case 'POST':
                return http_build_query($_POST);
                break;
            case 'DELETE':
                return http_build_query($_GET);
                break;
            case 'PUT':
                return http_build_query($_POST);
                break;
        }
    }
}

$modal = new Api();
$baseUrl = 'http://dev-api.zoova.ro';
echo $modal::getResponse($baseUrl . $modal->getPathInfo(), $modal->getParams(), '', $modal->getBody());
```